# Using a Set To Search inside a String

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, if-statement, set

So, lets say I have the following:

```
String = "A"

if String in {"A", "B", "C"}:
    print("True")

else:
    print("False")
```

Now this should definitely print the string "True".

Okay, now lets say we change it such that:

String = "ABCD"

My goal from this point is to use the same set from before but this time return "True" if any of the values are inside of the string given.

My idea:

```
String = "ABCD"

if {"A", "B", "C"} in String:
        print("True")

    else:
        print("False")
```

I tried this and it did not work.

I believe I could do this with a lot of if Statements, however I am hoping there's a way around that.

What would be the best way of accomplishing what I want to do?

Comment: You are probably looking for `all(i in String for i in {'A', 'B', 'C'})`

Comment: mhh ... where is the `Dictionary` from the tiltle of the question?

Comment: I thought that {} were dictionaries, sorry should I edit it?

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? If so, please consider accepting (green tick on left), so other users know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{"A", "B", "C"} is a set, and strings don't contain sets, so the in operator won't work in your particular example.

If you want to check if any value in your set is inside of the string, you can use the `any()` function.

```
String = "ABCD"
a_set = {"A", "B", "C"}
print(any(i in String for i in a_set))
>>>True
```

Comment: Why not just `print(all(i in String for i in {'A', 'B', 'C'}))`, no need for unnecessary if/else statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your string to `set` and test if the intersection of 2 sets is non-empty.

This is the Pythonic way to implement the above logic:

```
mystr = "ABCD"

if {"A", "B", "C"} & set(mystr):
    print("True")
```